# Why does this canvas content get cut off when oriented sideways?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an audio visualizer I've made and (I've increased the height cap of it so the problem is more clear) for some reason it just cuts off at a certain point and I haven't been able to figure it out. While the visualizer has this issue when oriented to the left like this, the problem does not exist when anchored normally to the bottom. Any help to figure this out would be greatly appreciated!

How it looks now \/

[image: bad lookikng]

How I want the height to look (but sideways so its extends to the end of the canvas horizontally)  \/

[image: normal looking]

This is the code for it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

   <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <script src="properties.js"></script>
        <script src="clockRefresh.js"></script>
       
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM Mono' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Share Tech Mono' rel='stylesheet'>
    
        <style>
             #time-panel {   
                  position: absolute;    
                  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);  
                  border-radius: 20px; 
                  
             }
             #hour, #min, #sec {
                  font-family: 'dm mono';
                  font-weight: 1000;                 
             }
             #clock {
                  display: table;
                  margin: 0 auto;
             }
             #audioCanvas {
                  border-radius: 20px; 
                  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
                  position: absolute;
             }
        </style>
        
   </head>
   <body onload="clock()"  > 
        <div id="time-panel">
             <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
             <span id="clock">
                  <span id="hour"></span>
                  <span id="min"></span>
                  <span id="sec"></span>
             </span>
        </div>

        <!-- Canvas where visualizer is drawn -->
        <canvas id="audioCanvas"></canvas>
       
      
        <!-- Script that creates said visualizer -->
        <script>
             // Get the audio canvas once the page has loaded
             let audioCanvas = document.getElementById('audioCanvas');

             // Get the 2D context of the canvas to draw on it in wallpaperAudioListener
             let audioCanvasCtx = audioCanvas.getContext('2d');

             // Setting internal canvas resolution to user screen resolution
             // (CSS canvas size differs from internal canvas size)
             audioCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
             audioCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;

             function wallpaperAudioListener(audioArray) {
                  audioCanvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height);

                  if (sessionStorage.getItem("audio-orientation") == "left" ||
                       sessionStorage.getItem("audio-orientation") == "right") {

                  

                       // Render bars along the full height of the canvas
                       var barWidth = Math.round(1.0 / 128.0 * audioCanvas.height);
                       var halfCount = audioArray.length / 2;
                  }
                  else {
                       // Render bars along the full width of the canvas
                       var barWidth = Math.round(1.0 / 128.0 * audioCanvas.width);
                       var halfCount = audioArray.length / 2;
                  }
                  // Begin with the left channel in red
                  audioCanvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
                  // Iterate over the first 64 array elements (0 - 63) for the left channel audio data
                  for (var i = 0; i < halfCount; i += parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("bar-amount"))) {
                       // Create an audio bar with its hight depending on the audio volume level of the current frequency
                       var height = audioCanvas.height * Math.min(audioArray[i], 1) * sessionStorage.getItem("bar-height");
                       audioCanvasCtx.fillRect(barWidth * i, audioCanvas.height - height * sessionStorage.getItem("bar-distortion"), barWidth, height);
                  }

                  // Now draw the right channel in blue
                  audioCanvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
                  // Iterate over the last 64 array elements (64 - 127) for the right channel audio data
                  for (var i = halfCount; i < audioArray.length; i += parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("bar-amount"))) {
                       // Create an audio bar with its hight depending on the audio volume level
                       // Using audioArray[191 - i] here to inverse the right channel for aesthetics
                       var height = audioCanvas.height * Math.min(audioArray[191 - i], 1) * sessionStorage.getItem("bar-height");;
                       audioCanvasCtx.fillRect(barWidth * i, audioCanvas.height - height * sessionStorage.getItem("bar-distortion"), barWidth, height);
                  }

                  if (sessionStorage.getItem("audio-orientation") == "left") {
                       //temp canvas to store rotation data
                       var tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
                       tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

                       tempCanvas.width = audioCanvas.width;
                       tempCanvas.height = audioCanvas.height;
                       tempCtx.drawImage(audioCanvas, 0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height);

                       // Now clear the portion to rotate.
                       audioCanvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height);

                       audioCanvasCtx.save();
                       // Translate (190/2 is half of the box we drew)
                       audioCanvasCtx.translate(audioCanvas.width / 2, 0);

                       // Rotate it
                       audioCanvasCtx.rotate(90 * Math.PI/180);

                       // Finally draw the image data from the temp canvas.
                       audioCanvasCtx.translate(audioCanvas.height / 45, -audioCanvas.width / 16);
                       audioCanvasCtx.width = audioCanvasCtx.width * 10;
                       audioCanvasCtx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height * 2, 0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height * 2);
                       audioCanvasCtx.restore();
                  }
             }


             // Register the audio listener provided by Wallpaper Engine.
             window.wallpaperRegisterAudioListener(wallpaperAudioListener);
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The code is based on [this](https://docs.wallpaperengine.io/en/web/audio/visualizer.html) which gives a bit more detail on how the code works. The `bar-values` are coming from another script that store settings changes.

### Updated with solution:

````html

```
 <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
      <script src="properties.js"></script>
      <script src="clockRefresh.js"></script>
     
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM Mono' rel='stylesheet'>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Share Tech Mono' rel='stylesheet'>
  
      <style>
           #time-panel {   
                position: absolute;    
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);  
                border-radius: 20px; 
                
           }
           #hour, #min, #sec {
                font-family: 'dm mono';
                font-weight: 1000;                 
           }
           #clock {
                display: table;
                margin: 0 auto;
           }
           #audioCanvas {
                border-radius: 20px; 
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
                position: absolute;
           }
      </style>
      
 </head>
 <body onload="clock()"  > 
      <div id="time-panel">
           <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
           <span id="clock">
                <span id="hour"></span>
                <span id="min"></span>
                <span id="sec"></span>
           </span>
      </div>

      <!-- Canvas where visualizer is drawn -->
      <canvas id="audioCanvas"></canvas>
     
    
      <!-- Script that creates said visualizer -->
      <script>
           // Get the audio canvas once the page has loaded
           let audioCanvas = document.getElementById('audioCanvas');

           // Get the 2D context of the canvas to draw on it in wallpaperAudioListener
           let audioCanvasCtx = audioCanvas.getContext('2d');

           // Setting internal canvas resolution to user screen resolution
           // (CSS canvas size differs from internal canvas size)
           audioCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
           audioCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;

           //temp canvas to store rotation data
           var offScreen = document.createElement("canvas"),
           offScreenCtx = offScreen.getContext("2d");


           function wallpaperAudioListener(audioArray) {
                audioCanvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height);

                if (sessionStorage.getItem("audio-orientation") == "left" ||
                     sessionStorage.getItem("audio-orientation") == "right") {

                     // Render bars along the full height of the canvas
                     var barWidth = Math.round(1.0 / 128.0 * audioCanvas.height);
                     var halfCount = audioArray.length / 2;
                }
                else {
                     // Render bars along the full width of the canvas
                     var barWidth = Math.round(1.0 / 128.0 * audioCanvas.width);
                     var halfCount = audioArray.length / 2;
                }
                // Begin with the left channel in red
                audioCanvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
                // Iterate over the first 64 array elements (0 - 63) for the left channel audio data
                for (var i = 0; i < halfCount; i += parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("bar-amount"))) {
                     // Create an audio bar with its hight depending on the audio volume level of the current frequency
                     var height = audioCanvas.height * Math.min(audioArray[i], 1) * sessionStorage.getItem("bar-height");
                     audioCanvasCtx.fillRect(barWidth * i, audioCanvas.height - height * sessionStorage.getItem("bar-distortion"), barWidth, height);
                }

                // Now draw the right channel in blue
                audioCanvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
                // Iterate over the last 64 array elements (64 - 127) for the right channel audio data
                for (var i = halfCount; i < audioArray.length; i += parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("bar-amount"))) {
                     // Create an audio bar with its hight depending on the audio volume level
                     // Using audioArray[191 - i] here to inverse the right channel for aesthetics
                     var height = audioCanvas.height * Math.min(audioArray[191 - i], 1) * sessionStorage.getItem("bar-height");
                     audioCanvasCtx.fillRect(barWidth * i, audioCanvas.height - height * sessionStorage.getItem("bar-distortion"), barWidth, height);
                }

                if (sessionStorage.getItem("audio-orientation") == "left") {

                     offScreen.width = audioCanvas.width;
                     offScreen.height = audioCanvas.height;
                     offScreenCtx.drawImage(audioCanvas, 0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height);

                     // Now clear the portion to rotate.
                     audioCanvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height);

                     audioCanvasCtx.save();
                     // Translate (190/2 is half of the box we drew)
                     audioCanvasCtx.translate(audioCanvas.width, 0);

                     // Rotate it
                     audioCanvasCtx.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);

                     // Finally draw the image data from the temp canvas.
                     audioCanvasCtx.translate(audioCanvas.height / 45, -audioCanvas.width / 16);
                     audioCanvasCtx.width = audioCanvasCtx.width * 10;
                     audioCanvasCtx.drawImage(offScreen, 0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height * 1.9);
                     audioCanvasCtx.restore();
                }
           }


           // Register the audio listener provided by Wallpaper Engine.
           window.wallpaperRegisterAudioListener(wallpaperAudioListener);
      </script>
 </body>
```

````

Comment: What are the values for `"bar-amount"`, `"bar-distortion"` and `"bar-height"`? Is audioArray a `Float32Array `or an `Uint8Array`?

Comment: @obscure oh sorry, it is an array of floating point numbers so float32 im assuming. `bar-amount`, `bar-distortion`, and `bar-height` are user input from a slider. `bar-height` and `bar-distortion` are both decimal numbers and `bar-amount` an integer. They are coming in from another script that detects and stores changed setting/property values. it is based on this code https://docs.wallpaperengine.io/en/web/audio/visualizer.html

Comment: Hey @Matt - I just wanted to have some sample values for those three variables (maybe those that you've used while making the screenshots) so I can try to replicate your scenario. =)

Comment: @obscure right, `bar-amount` can be a number from 1 (min slider value) to 10 (max slider value),  `bar-height` can be a number from 1.0 to 10.0, and `bar-distortion` can be any value from 1.00 to 3.00.

Comment: oh one thing I've forgot - is #audioCanvas always quadratic or also rectangular (in which case it won't be possible to rotate and fill the entire canvas without cutting off some parts of the unrotated canvas or distorting the image by stretching it to fill the available space)?

Comment: @obscure i believe its always quadratic i think. each bar of the visualizer represents the volume level (stored in the float32 array) of a single different frequency coming from your computer audio .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're playing with the width & height of the canvas - and thus the size of your bars - at two different places:

```
 if (sessionStorage.getItem("audio-orientation") == "left" ||
   sessionStorage.getItem("audio-orientation") == "right") {

   var barWidth = Math.round(1.0 / 128.0 * audioCanvas.height);
   var halfCount = audioArray.length / 2;
 } else {
   // Render bars along the full width of the canvas
   var barWidth = Math.round(1.0 / 128.0 * audioCanvas.width);
   var halfCount = audioArray.length / 2;
 }
```

and later on as you finally draw the temporary canvas back to `audioCanvas`.

As we simply want to stretch the image to the available space if the canvas is rotated, we don't actually need a different `barWidth`. The stretching is happening at the `drawImage()` call by reversing the width & height.

As a side note - at the moment you're creating a new `<canvas>` element each time the audio listener fires. That's quite a lot. For performance reasons I'd recommend creating an `OffscreenCanvas` or a regular canvas once at startup and re-use that.

Here's an example:

```js
let settings = {
  "audio-orientation": "left",
  "bar-amount": 1,
  "bar-distortion": 1,
  "bar-height": 1
}
let audioData = [];
for (let a = 0; a < 128; a++) {
  audioData.push((Math.sin(a / 8) + 1) / 2);
}

let audioCanvas = document.getElementById('audioCanvas');

let audioCanvasCtx = audioCanvas.getContext('2d');
audioCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
audioCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;

var offScreen = document.createElement("canvas");
var offScreenContext = offScreen.getContext("2d");

function wallpaperAudioListener(audioArray) {
  audioCanvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height);

  var barWidth = Math.round(1.0 / 128.0 * audioCanvas.width);
  var halfCount = audioArray.length / 2;
  audioCanvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';

  for (var i = 0; i < halfCount; i += parseInt(settings["bar-amount"])) {
    var height = audioCanvas.height * Math.min(audioArray[i], 1) * settings["bar-height"];
    audioCanvasCtx.fillRect(barWidth * i, audioCanvas.height - height * settings["bar-distortion"], barWidth, height);
  }

  audioCanvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
  for (var i = halfCount; i < audioArray.length; i += parseInt(settings["bar-amount"])) {
    var height = audioCanvas.height * Math.min(audioArray[191 - i], 1) * settings["bar-height"];
    audioCanvasCtx.fillRect(barWidth * i, audioCanvas.height - height * settings["bar-distortion"], barWidth, height);
  }

  if (settings["audio-orientation"] == "left") {
    offScreen.width = audioCanvas.width;
    offScreen.height = audioCanvas.height;
    offScreenContext.clearRect(0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height);
    offScreenContext.drawImage(audioCanvas, 0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height);
    audioCanvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, audioCanvas.width, audioCanvas.height);
    audioCanvasCtx.save();
    audioCanvasCtx.translate(audioCanvas.width, 0);
    audioCanvasCtx.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
    audioCanvasCtx.drawImage(offScreen, 0, 0, audioCanvas.height, audioCanvas.width);
    audioCanvasCtx.restore();
  }
}

wallpaperAudioListener(audioData);
```

```html
<canvas id="audioCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to edit my code slightly to make it work.